# How to configure BeyondCompare to use Latin1 or ISO/IEC 8859-1 Encoding?

Tags: encoding, beyondcompare

I would like inform BeyondCompare that the encoding of my file is Latin1 or ISO 8859-1.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To force a character encoding instead of using the auto-detected encoding, click the dropdown below the left or right path edit in the Text Compare. The default setting of the dropdown will probably say ANSI or UTF-8.

The dropdown lists a popular subset of supported character encodings. If you're using an encoding that isn't on the dropdown, click the Rules toolbar button in the Text Compare. Go to the Format tab. Click the dropdown for Left encoding override or Right encoding override and select an encoding.

In addition to forcing an encoding for a specific session, you can force an encoding for a specific file format (file mask). Open Tools > File Formats. Select the format that matches your files. Go to the Conversion tab. Change Encoding from Detect to the encoding of your files, then Save.